# Different default Value for different views from a list

Tags: list, list-view, default-value

This is what I am trying to do.  I have a list with 3 views.
Each View will have default text boxes but each will also have their own unique form elements which I will make viewable based on the view selected
So when a user addes from one of the respective views, it will go to the correct view list.
That's where I am stuck on.  How would I do this?  Can their be different views from the same list with 3 default values?
Below is a mock up of my List structure:

So I have a List called "List A"
I have one field called "Type"
I have 3 views "ListA1", "ListA2", and ListA3".
The "Type" field will have a default value of "ListA1Item" which will show up for the "ListA1" view, only.
Repeat for "ListA2/ListA2Item" and "ListA3/ListA3Item".

Is it possible?  Could this be triggered from a link to the List/View Form and maybe based on the url parameters (say "&listtype=ListA3Item") go to a redirect page with some Javascript that will send to the appropriate NewForm page?

Hopefully this all makes sense.  Thanks

Comment: Thought I had understand, but I'm not sure. Maybe you're thinking abour *source* URL parameter? Or?

Comment: @Salah, Thanks for the reply.  I just kept it simple and made 3 Lists.  And yes, I was thinking the Source URL Parameter and adding another parameter to it.  But already completed the 3 lists and it's working fine.